# "tessellation" of set of points in 2D with convex polygons

Tags: geometry, triangulation, tessellations

I have a set of points in 2D, that I want to 'triangulate' with the lowest number of convex polygons. Is there an algorithm to do this? (like [Delaunay triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation), but with polygons)

Remarks:

- I have seen many approaches to optimal splitting up of a given set of points into *triangles* (in 2-D; or simplices in n-D), but none for larger polygons.
- I have also seen many approaches to tessellating the plane with polygons *of equal shape* and without regarding any previously defined points.
- Voronoi tesselations are always convex; I was wondering if there is a way to find a second set of points, so, that the original set of points forms the vertices of voronoi cells of the first. In that case the voronoi tesselation would be the sought tessellation. I can't quite see it yet.

If someone can point me in the right direction, that would be appreciated.

---

**edit 1**

Starting from a Delaunay triangulation, I identified all edges that could be removed in a first step.

[image]

There are some which are obvious, as they are inside a 4-polygon of which all edges cannot be removed - such as the one indicated by the red arrow. Any final solution will have this edge removed.

However, there are many 'removable' edges that can only be removed if some other removable edge is *not* removed, and vice versa. Therefor, I need some criterion to select which to keep and which to remove. I was wondering about using circumscribed circles, like some Delaunay algorithms use, but haven't tried it yet. The idea would be to calculate the circumscribed circle for each polygon that results from the removal of a 'candidate' edge - and picking the one that only includes its own points in the resulting polygon. It's not immediately obvious to me, though, if this is necessarily leading to the optimal solution. (It's not even clear to me that the Delaunay triangulation is always a starting point with a path to that solution.) I'm gonna have to give it some more thought.

---

**edit 2**

I've gone and implemented an algorithm that's a bit shaky but good enough for my purposes; I've added it as an answer. Someone more mathematically gifted is surely able to find a better solution; if so, please do comment / add your own answer.

Comment: Do the Delaunay triangulation, then glue triangles into polygons in a greedy way, as long as the result is convex.

Comment: Hey Ivan thanks for that suggestion. I started on doing just that, by looking at the edges in a Delaunay triangulation which could be removed while remaining convexness. It's not immediately obvious, though, which ones to pick to get the optimal end result - I've edited the question

Comment: Generally speaking, polygons don't have circumcircles. I'd start by removing the longest edges first. Here I'm thinking in terms of "good enough" rather than "optimal".

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, kinda.

What I *have* done: written an algorithm that identifies the edges that can be removed, and which then removes those edges based on a certain criterion: remove the largest edge first, or the edge that creates the most acute angle first.

What I have *not* done:

- optimized in any way for speed;
- tried to find the 'best' wall to remove, e.g. to end up with the least polygons.

Code (python) can be found [here](https://github.com/rwijtvliet/polygonation). There is also an option to turn off the convex condition.

Here some images:

n = 150

`convex = True`

[image]

`convex = False`

[image]

I hope this is useful to someone.

Comment: Does the polygon count differ much between the three criteria that you used?

Comment: I didn't look into that (yet) - for me it's more about their shape, and there is clearly a lot of variation, at least with `convex=False`. But this is a bit harder to grasp in a number.

But, it's a good idea to run some stats on the various outputs, and polygon count is a useful one. I'm also thinking about the distribution of their area and of their convexity. Any others you'd like to see? Then I'll include them once I get around to adding stats to the output.

Comment: No, it was just idle curiosity. I think this is a fascinating question, and it feels to me like it must be something that others have tried to tackle before, but I have no solutions to offer. Another thing to think about is boundary effects. They could play a significant role when $n$ is as low as $150$ (less with larger $n$, but I don't know what size $n$ you are aiming for). To take out boundary effects when comparing methods, you could do your testing on a torus, i.e. do Asteroids-style wrap-around.